# Rest API version header in SwaggerUI

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to use Springfox SwaggerUI for my Rest API (spring-mvc) documentation.
I use version header in @RequestMapping annotation, but if I have two versions of same method, in SwaggerUI I can see only one.

For example:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/users", headers = "X-API-VERSION=1")
public List<User> getUsersV1(){...}

@GetMapping(value = "/users", headers = "X-API-VERSION=2")
public List<User> getUsersV2(){...}
```

Above code results in only one method visible in api documentation.

Is there any option to configure Swagger to differ endpoints with consideration of my version header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I have found solution to my problem, maybe it will help someone in the future. I add "#v" suffix to path using PathDecorator.

Now I can see all my methods in generated documentation.

```
@Component
@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 70)
public class VersionPathDecorator implements PathDecorator {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VersionPathDecorator.class);

@Override
public Function<String, String> decorator(PathContext context) {
    return (path) -> {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(path);
        Field parent = null;
        try {
            parent = PathContext.class.getDeclaredField("parent");
            parent.setAccessible(true);
            RequestMappingContext rmc = (RequestMappingContext) parent.get(context);
            rmc.headers()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(h -> RequestHeader.X_API_VERSION.headerName.equals(h.getName()))
                    .map(NameValueExpression::getValue)
                    .findFirst()
                    .ifPresent(v -> sb.append("#v").append(v));

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.error("path decoration failed", e);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    };
}

@Override
public boolean supports(DocumentationContext documentationContext) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swagger identifies services by its endpoint.

Each feature must respond to a different endpoint, and headers for that function should not be used.

If you are using REST services read a bit about Restfull and follow its principles. This url can help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijqy.html

Comment: Thanks for answer. Versioning api resources with version header is existing solution and I can not change it. I can see all endpoints with all versions if I enable url templating on Docket bean, but its not a good solution to my issue. I would like to implement one of Springfox BuilderPlugins to include my version header in endpoint path. http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#plugins-available-for-extensibility

Comment: Yes, its possible but is not the best practice. Think of changing your development because you can have problems in future when you try to read your code or when someone try to do it.